# Is *.xyz a standard file format in computational chemistry?

Tags: computational-chemistry

- https://youtu.be/f6K8k0sH2TY

The above YouTube tutorial talks about a file format called XYZ.

Later, the tutor uses this format to compute the bond length and bond graph of a molecule.

Is `*.xyz` a standard file format in computational chemistry? Or did this tutor just make it up for the convenience of his computations?

If this is a standard format, then is he following the standard in his XYZ files?

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial series elected the [.xyz file format](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FileFormats/Utility_Formats.html) because this [*utility format*](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FileFormats/Utility_Formats.html) is syntactically simple plain ASCII, without a patent limiting its use, and widely used.  By custom in this community, the Cartesian coordinates are (implicitly) set in Angstrom ($1 Å = \pu{10E-10 m} = \pu{0.1 nm} = \pu{100 pm}$) because it is a unit of length close to typical bond lengths (the $\ce{C=C}$ double bond in ethene fore example $\pu{134 pm}$, or $\pu{1.34 Å}$, [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond_length)).

- the organization of information eases to extract/parse the information with a script or program you might want to write for yourself / one of the many structure viewers around
- in comparison to other file formats to represent a molecular structure, its content is very basic.  Some information, for instance which atoms are connected with each other, or the relevant bond order (e.g., single, double, aromatic, triple) organized in blocks (see for example *chemical table* formats as in .mol and .sdf (an [entry on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_table_file#SDF))) are missing. No indicator if the structure consists of one, or multiple molecules, nor if there is a charge, either.
- it is not the input file format to launch one of the more advanced computations in typical quantum chemical programs (MOPAC, Gaussian, GAMESS-UK/GAMESS-US, etc.).  In addition to the atoms' coordinates and the intended computation (and level of theory, keyword *basis set*), they expect an input explicit about spin multiplicity (singlet, doublet, triplett) and  overall charge of the structure submitted.

  Departing from for example a .sdf file, there is help to prepare these input files.  If not already provided by the program itself, [openbabel](https://github.com/openbabel/openbabel) (most recent documentation [here](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), specific to quantum chemistry formats [here](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FileFormats/Computational_chemistry_Formats.html)), input generators of [Avogadro](https://two.avogadro.cc/), or [gabedit](https://gabedit.sourceforge.net/)
  are among the assistants available.

To best of my knowledge, there is no (ISO like) standard regarding the representation of the (x,y,z) coordinates as `3F10.5`.  If you would like a consistent representation of your data, you always can request openbabel in lines of

```shell
obabel input.xyz -O output.xyz
```

(additional examples of application [here](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Command-line_tools/babel.html#examples)) to «tidy up» .xyz files to stick to the `F10.5` format for each column.